# typedef function pointer -> initialization from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, struct, function-pointers, typedef, compiler-warnings

I'm having trouble understanding the cause of this warning:

```
menu-file-select.c:41:29: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
```

The offending code is:

```
typedef int (*FileSelectFilter)(const char*, struct dirent*);

typedef struct {
    const char *dir; //the directory path to read
    const char *out; //where to copy the selected path
    int outLen; //length of out buffer
    FileSelectFilter *filter; //optional filter function
} FileSelectParams;

void showFileSelectMenu(FileSelectParams *params) {
    /* ... */
    FileSelectFilter filter = params->filter; // <-- warning generated here.
    if(filter && !filter(path, ent)) continue;
    /* ... */
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    /* ... */
    FileSelectParams fsel = {
        .dir    = setting.lastpath,
        .out    = RomPath,
        .outLen = sizeof(RomPath) - 1,
        .filter = FileSelectFilter_Roms,
    };
    showFileSelectMenu(&fsel);
    /* ... */
}

int FileSelectFilter_Roms(const char *path, struct dirent *file) {
    /* ... */
}
```

As far as I can tell, `FileSelectFilter_Roms` matches the `FileSelectFilter` typedef, so I don't understand why I'm being told the type is incompatible. The program seems to work anyway, but having this warning here bothers me.

Comment: `FileSelectFilter` is already a pointer to a function (as per typedef). So in `FileSelectParams`, `filter` is defined as a pointer to a pointer to a function - drop the `*` !

Comment: Why not make this answer. @isedev

Comment: very well, since I have some time available...

Comment: As an alternative (if you don't like `typedef`ed pointers), you can `typedef` the function rather than a pointer to it: `typedef int FileSelectFilter(const char *, struct dirent *);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have defined `FileSelectFilter` as a pointer to a function in the typedef:

```
typedef int (*FileSelectFilter)(const char*, struct dirent*);
```

In `FileSelectPararms`, you define `filter` member as:

```
FileSelectFilter *filter;
```

This means that `filter` is actually a pointer to a pointer to a function. This is the reason why you are getting the error in the assignment `FileSelectFilter filter = params->filter;`.

The `filter` member should simply be defined as:

```
FileSelectFilter filter;
```